# How do I correctly get a String from an async Function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am still new in whole Flutter environment so any help is more than welcome! While doing signUp process in my app, one of the steps is to upload user profile picture. I want to store profile picture on Firebase Storage and rename it to User UID from Firebase Authentication. The problem is that User UID I get after whole signUp process is done and therefore I have to use here Future class to get it.

I want to save it like this so I can easier find profile photo of each user(my app has multiple user roles, User A,B,C....) and fetch it when needed

```dart
Future<String> getUID() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  final String uid = user.uid;
  _getUID(uid);
  return uid;
}

String getterUID;

void _getUID(String uid) {
  getterUID = uid;
}

Future<void> uploadPicture() async {
  final StorageReference firebaseStorageReference =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(getUID.toString());
  final StorageUploadTask task =
      firebaseStorageReference.putFile(_pictureData['image']);
}
```

I manage to upload picture to Firebase Storage but it is uploaded with name(1) and not with User UID from the Firebase Auth. Any tips and tricks how to make it work? Thanks in advance :)

(1) Closure: () => Future from Function 'getUID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting the function `getUID` to a string instead of evaluating the function and converting the result of your function to a string, which you do not even need to do as your function already returns a `String`, just inside of a `Future`.

There are two steps to this:

1. Change the function reference to a function call:

```dart
getUID -> getUID()
```

1. `await` the `Future` to get your `String` result:

```dart
getUID() -> await getUID()
```

Your final function would look like this:

```dart
Future<void> uploadPicture() async {
  final StorageReference firebaseStorageReference =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(await getUID());
  final StorageUploadTask task =
      firebaseStorageReference.putFile(_pictureData['image']);
}
```

Comment: thank you fur such a fast answer! I used you advice but now I get another error 
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
any tips how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @zero_cool You are not authenticated, i.e. `currentUser` returned `null` - there is no user in your current session. This is, however, unrelated to your original problem.